# Is BV a Banach lattice with respect to a special cone?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $BV$ be the space of functions on $[0,1]$ of bounded variations equipped with the standard norm $\Vert f\Vert := \Vert f\Vert_{L^1} + \mathrm{var}(f)$, where $\mathrm{var}(f)$ is the total variation of $f$.
Consider a cone
\begin{equation}
\mathcal C:=\left\{ f \in BV : f \ge 0, \; \mathrm{var}( f ) \le \int f dx \right\}
\end{equation}
(this cone has a [background in dynamical systems theory](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385798118023).)
Introduce a partial order $\preceq$ on $BV$ by $f\preceq g$ iff $g-f \in \mathcal C$. Then, is $(BV,\Vert \cdot \Vert ,\preceq)$ a Banach lattice?